# angular redirect with $location path outside the route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an index.html page that has a `$routeProvider` inside. Whenever I go on a new path inside this page, I check to see if the user is logged in. Something like this:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, authService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.title = next.$$route.title;

        authService.isLogged().then(null, function() {
            $location.path('/login');
        });
    });
});
```

I have a separate page called login.html. If the user is not logged in, I want a javascript line to redirect him to login.html. With this example I copy / pasted , if I have the URL

```
localhost/myapp/#/home
```

it redirects me to

```
localhost/myapp/#/login
```

but I want it to redirect me to

```
localhost/myapp/login
```

widthout `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use plain js, if your base is allways `/myapp`, `login` is enough:

```js
$window.location.href = 'login'; //If you care about testability
window.location.href = 'login'; //If you don't
```

Comment: the first one doesnt work, i dont know why but the second one works exactly how i wanted to , thank you very much Marcel Gwerder

Comment: Did you inject `$window` like you did it with `$location`?